# clicking like button results in nothing after adding open graph meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am adding dynamic like buttons to all the items on a website of a client, they do work now (after a lot of trial and error) but it still asks the user to confirm the like.
I tried the facebook debug tool and it gives me a bunch of open graph warnings and like button warnings that should be fixed.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bowmanmusic.be%2Fbowman%2F

So I add all the required open graph meta tags to the head of my page like so:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="159728304104034" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Bowman" />
<meta property="og:type" content="band" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.bowmanmusic.be/bowman" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.bowmanmusic.be/bowman/images/bowman01.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Bowman Music" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Bowman website" />
```

And now it still asks the user for confirmation but it doesn't register the like anymore i.e. it doesn't appear in the timeline nor in the event log.

I am loading the fb sdk like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

And this is my php for the like button:

```
echo "<div class=\"fbbutton\"><fb:like href=\"http://www.bowmanmusic.be/bowman/index.php?id=",$id,"\" send=\"false\" layout=\"button_count\" show_faces=\"false\"></fb:like></div>";
```

I would like to get rid of the need for confirmation and off course that the like event shows up on the users timeline.

Does anybody now how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The way you include the like button is not good (especially the synchronous inclusion of the javascript SDK). Please use the generator on the like plugin page:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

also, i don´t see any like button on your page. All menu entries just lead to the same image. Keep in mind that every page that has a like button MUST be public (not behind a user login or whatever).

Btw, you should use an App Id for the Like button (see plugin generator), should prevent you from getting the confirmation.

...not to mention that every page that can be liked must have the correct open graph tags, not just the homepage. So, if you want to like "http://www.bowmanmusic.be/bowman/index.php?id=xxx", you have to make sure that the specific site got the correct tags, including the correct url with index.php and stuff. In any case, you should rewrite those urls, but that´s another long story...

Comment: I just added a new item with a like button, i forgot i deleted all the trial posts for a sec. I tried using the provided code on the plugin page but then it just doesn't work at all. But i guess trying again couldn't hurt.